# Google is not ranking Magento based website

Tags: seo, google, magento

I cannot seem to receive a google page rank for encryptstick.com the site has been live for about 5 months now, we have very good linking from sources such as pcworld.com, cnet.com, pcmag.com etc.

The website is magento based, could there be an issue with magento that is blocking google from reading & ranking the site correctly?

I've run the site through google webmaster tools as how google bot sees the site. the code is posted below.

Does anyone have any comments as to why this site will not rank?

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Wed, 22 Dec 2010 02:19:03 GMT Server: Apache X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.13 Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0 Pragma: no-cache Set-Cookie: frontend=635d30c52325df09c93409cb35461f76; expires=Wed, 22-Dec-2010 03:19:03 GMT; path=/; domain=encryptstick.com; HttpOnly Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100 Connection: Keep-Alive Transfer-Encoding: chunked Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"> <head> <title>Encrypt Stick™ - 3 in 1 Digital Privacy Software - USB Encryption, Private Web Browser &amp; Password Manager</title> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> <meta name="description" content="Insure your digital privacy with Encrypt Stick digital privacy software. Everyone has private digital files that need extra security -  Keep your sensitive files hidden and secure at all times." /> <meta name="keywords" content="protect files flash drive usb Encryptstick protection identity private" /> <meta name="robots" content="INDEX,FOLLOW" /> <meta name="author" content="ENC Security Systems Inc.">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://encryptstick.com/skin/frontend/default/default/css/reset.css" media="all" /> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://encryptstick.com/skin/frontend/default/default/css/960_24_col.css" media="all" />

<link rel="icon" href="http://encryptstick.com/skin/frontend/default/default/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" /> <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://encryptstick.com/skin/frontend/default/default/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" /> <script type="text/javascript"> //<![CDATA[
    var BLANK_URL = 'http://encryptstick.com/js/blank.html';
    var BLANK_IMG = 'http://encryptstick.com/js/spacer.gif'; //]]> </script>


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://encryptstick.com/skin/frontend/base/default/css/widgets.css" media="all" /> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://encryptstick.com/skin/frontend/default/default/css/styles.css" media="all" /> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://encryptstick.com/skin/frontend/default/default/css/print.css" media="print" /> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://encryptstick.com/js/prototype/prototype.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://encryptstick.com/js/prototype/validation.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://encryptstick.com/js/scriptaculous/builder.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://encryptstick.com/js/scriptaculous/effects.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://encryptstick.com/js/scriptaculous/dragdrop.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://encryptstick.com/js/scriptaculous/controls.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://encryptstick.com/js/scriptaculous/slider.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://encryptstick.com/js/varien/js.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://encryptstick.com/js/varien/form.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://encryptstick.com/js/varien/menu.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://encryptstick.com/js/mage/translate.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://encryptstick.com/js/mage/cookies.js"></script> <!--[if lt IE 8]> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://encryptstick.com/skin/frontend/default/default/css/styles-ie.css" media="all" /> <![endif]--> <!--[if lt IE 7]> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://encryptstick.com/js/lib/ds-sleight.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://encryptstick.com/skin/frontend/base/default/js/ie6.js"></script> <![endif]-->

<script type="text/javascript"> //<![CDATA[ optionalZipCountries = []; //]]> </script> <script type="text/javascript">var Translator
= new Translate([]);</script><meta name="google-site-verification" content="2JhNAp-g4AbP67EhpBsV1gSpf-SUSbjdGa4ATzasr2Y" /> </head> <body class=" cms-index-index cms-home">

<div class="container_24 header">    <div class="grid_7 alpha logo">   <h1 class="logo"><strong>Encrypt Stick Portable USB Encryption Software</strong><a href="http://encryptstick.com/" title="Encrypt Stick Portable USB Encryption Software" class="logo" name="thetop"><img src="http://encryptstick.com/skin/frontend/default/default/images/logo.png" alt="Encrypt Stick Portable USB Encryption Software" /></a></h1>  </div>    <div class="grid_17">   <div class="quick-access alignright">
        <form action="https://encryptstick.com/newsletter/subscriber/new/" method="post" id="newsletter-validate-detail">
        <label for="newsletter">Newsletter Signup:</label><br />
            <input type="text" name="email" id="newsletter" title="Sign up for our newsletter" class="input-text required-entry validate-email textbox"  value="Enter Your Email Address" onfocus="this.value=''; this.style.color = '#000000';" onblur="if (this.value == '') { this.value = 'Enter Your E-Mail Address'; this.style.color = '#777777'; }" /> 
            <button type="submit" title="Subscribe" class="button"><span><span>Subscribe</span></span></button>
      </form>
        <br />       <ul class="links">
            <li class="first" ><a href="https://encryptstick.com/customer/account/" title="My Account" >My Account</a></li>
            <li ><a href="http://encryptstick.com/checkout/cart/" title="My Cart" class="top-link-cart">My Cart</a></li>
            <li ><a href="http://encryptstick.com/checkout/" title="Checkout" class="top-link-checkout">Checkout</a></li>
            <li class=" last" ><a href="https://encryptstick.com/customer/account/login/" title="Log In" >Log In</a></li>
    </ul> </div>  </div>    <div class="clear"></div> </div>

<div class="container_24 nav-container">
    <div class="nav-container">
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="http://encryptstick.com/"><span>Home</span></a></li>


  <li onmouseover="toggleMenu(this,1)" onmouseout="toggleMenu(this,0)" class="level0 nav-1 parent">   <a href="http://encryptstick.com/what-is-encrypt-stick"><span>Encrypt Stick&trade;</span></a>    <ul class="level0">
    <li class="level1 nav-1-1"><a href="http://encryptstick.com/what-is-encrypt-stick"><span>What is Encrypt Stick&trade;?</span></a></li>
                <li class="level1 nav-1-1"><a href="http://encryptstick.com/browser-overview"><span class="new" >Private Browser</span></a></li>
                <li class="level1 nav-1-1"><a href="http://encryptstick.com/password-manager-overview"><span>Password Manager</span></a></li> 
               <li class="level1 nav-1-1"><a href="http://encryptstick.com/free-vs-paid"><span>Feature Comparisons</span></a></li>    </ul>   </li>
     <li><a href="http://encryptstick.com/download"><span>Free Download</span></a></li>
        <li onmouseover="toggleMenu(this,1)" onmouseout="toggleMenu(this,0)" class="level0 nav-2 parent"><a href="http://encryptstick.com/products/encrypt-stick-instant-license.html"><span>Purchase</span></a>




        </li>

        <li onmouseover="toggleMenu(this,1)" onmouseout="toggleMenu(this,0)" class="level0 nav-3 parent"><a href="http://encryptstick.com/support"><span>Support</span></a>
         <ul class="level0">
          <li class="level1 nav-3-1"><a href="/support"><span>Support Center</span></a></li>
          <li class="level1 nav-3-2"><a href="http://encryptstick.com/how-to"><span>How To Videos</span></a></li>
         </ul>
        </li>

        <li onmouseover="toggleMenu(this,1)" onmouseout="toggleMenu(this,0)" class="level0 nav-4 parent"><a href="http://encryptstick.com/press-room"><span>In The News</span></a>
         <ul class="level0">
          <li class="level1 nav-4-1"><a href="http://encryptstick.com/press-room"><span>Press Room</span></a></li>
                <li class="level1 nav-4-2"><a href="http://encryptstick.com/press-releases"><span>Press Releases</span></a></li>
          <li class="level1 nav-4-3"><a href="http://encryptstick.com/press-reviews"><span>Press Reviews </span></a></li>
          <li class="level1 nav-4-4"><a href="http://encryptstick.com/press-kit"><span>Press Kit</span></a></li>
         </ul>

        <li class="last"><a href="http://encryptstick.com/contact-us"><span>Contact</span></a></li>

            </ul>

    <div class="nav-buy-now"><a href="http://encryptstick.com/products/encrypt-stick-instant-license.html"><img src="http://encryptstick.com/skin/frontend/default/default/images/nav-buy-now.jpg" alt="Buy Now" /></a></div>

</div> </div>

<script type="text/javascript"> function bookmarksite(title, url){ if (document.all) window.external.AddFavorite(url, title); else if (window.sidebar) window.sidebar.addPanel(title, url, "") } </script> <a class="bookmark" href="javascript:bookmarksite('Encrypt Stick - Digital Privacy Manager', 'http://encryptstick.com')"></a> 
    <div class="container_24">
         <noscript>
        <div class="noscript">
            <div class="noscript-inner">
                <p><strong>We detected that your JavaScript seem to be disabled.</strong></p>
                <p>You must have JavaScript enabled in your browser to utilize the functionality of this website.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </noscript>
            </div>
      <div class="container_24 page">

         <div class="container_24">
          <div class="showcase_wrapper">
           <ul id="protofade">
                        <li style="display: none; "><a href="/holiday-promo"><img src="http://encryptstick.com/skin/frontend/default/default/images/homepage/holidays.png" alt="Holiday Promotion" /></a></li>
                        <li style="display: none; "><a href="/stories/bob-and-mary"><img src="http://encryptstick.com/skin/frontend/default/default/images/homepage/slide_1.png" alt="Slide 1" /></a></li>
                        <li style="display: none; "><a href="/stories/louise"><img src="http://encryptstick.com/skin/frontend/default/default/images/homepage/slide_2.png" alt="Slide 2" /></a></li>
                        <li style="display: none; "><a href="/stories/cindy"><img src="http://encryptstick.com/skin/frontend/default/default/images/homepage/slide_3.png" alt="Slide 3" /></a></li>
                    </ul>

                    <script src="/js/prototype/protofade.1.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
                        function StartUp() {
                            new Protofade('protofade', { delay:7, duration:1.0}); 
                            }
                            document.observe ('dom:loaded', StartUp);
                    </script>

          </div>
                <div class="metal_showcase">
                 <a href="/press-room"><img src="http://encryptstick.com/skin/frontend/default/default/images/press-room/PCWorld-logo.JPG" alt="PC World Review" /></a>
                    <a href="/press-room"><img src="http://encryptstick.com/skin/frontend/default/default/images/press-room/CNET-logo.JPG" alt="CNET News Review" /></a>
                    <a href="/press-room"><img src="http://encryptstick.com/skin/frontend/default/default/images/press-room/eweek.jpg" alt="eWeek Review" /></a>
                    <a href="/press-room"><img src="http://encryptstick.com/skin/frontend/default/default/images/press-room/network-world.jpg" alt="Network World Review" /></a>
                </div>
         <div class="clear"></div>
         </div>
                    <div class="container_24 dark-grey-gradient">
    <div class="grid_22 push_1 list-items-large">
     <div class="grid_9 suffix_1 alpha">
      <h3 class="homepage-subs">Protect Your Files.</h3>
      <p class="large">Everyone has private digital files that need extra security. They&rsquo;re the ones on your computer or other devices that could cause serious consequences if they fell into the wrong hands: photos, videos, financial records, identity passwords and sensitive documents. Lost or stolen devices, or violated files, put you at considerable risk of embarrassment, identity theft, financial loss and marital problems -- even job loss. Why take a chance when you can take a few seconds to permanently secure your digital privacy?</p>
      <p class="large"><a href="/what-is-encrypt-stick" class="bold">Learn how to protect your files &raquo;</a></p>
     </div>
     <div class="grid_12 omega"><img src="http://encryptstick.com/skin/frontend/default/default/images/encrypt-files.png" alt="Secure Private Files" style="padding-top:10px;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>    </div> 

            <div class="grid_22 push_1 alpha">
             <div class="shadow-divider"></div>    </div>
                <div class="container_24">
    <div class="grid_22 push_1 list-items-large">
     <div class="grid_12 suffix_1 alpha">
      <img src="http://encryptstick.com/skin/frontend/default/default/images/private-browsing.jpg" alt="Private Browsing">
     </div>
     <div class="grid_9 omega">
      <h3 class="homepage-subs">Protect Your Web Browsing.</h3>
                        <p class="large">The Encrypt Stick&trade; Digital Privacy Browser runs off any flash drive, it provides unparalleled web surfing privacy and leaves no trace whatsoever on the host computer. </p>
      <p class="large">Keep your web surfing activities completely private. Private from the boss, spouse, kids, friends, hackers, whomever… while you're doing online banking, surfing personal sites, web shopping or anything else that you want to keep private. Bottom line – What happens on the flash drive stays on the flash drive!</p>
                        <p class="large"><a href="/browser-overview" class="bold">Learn more about private browsing &raquo;</a></p>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>    </div> 

            <div class="grid_22 push_1 alpha">
             <div class="shadow-divider"></div>    </div>
       <div class="container_24 space-bottom">
    <div class="grid_22 push_1 list-items-large ">
     <div class="grid_9 suffix_1 alpha">
      <h3 class="homepage-subs">Protect Your Passwords.</h3>

                        <p class="large">Passwords are a key weapon against identity theft.  The stronger they are the more protection they offer.  The stronger they are, the more difficult to remember.
                            Encrypt Stick&trade; Password manager eliminates the need to remember your passwords by saving them in an encrypted database on your flash drive.
                            The searchable, easy to use database means you can carry your passwords with you on your Flash drive and use them to access your banking accounts, online shopping accounts, web site logins, email accounts etc from any computer, in complete privacy and with total security.  With Encrypt Stick&trade; you only have to remember one password.
      </p>

                        <p class="large"><a href="/password-manager-overview" class="bold">Never forget a password again - Learn More &raquo;</a></p>
     </div>
     <div class="grid_12 omega"><img src="http://encryptstick.com/skin/frontend/default/default/images/password-manager.jpg" alt="Password Manager"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>    </div> 

            <div class="container_24">
            <center><a href="#thetop" class="thetop">Back to the Top</a></center>
            </div>

      <div class="clear"></div> </div> <div class="container_24 page-bottom"></div>

        <div id="footer_wrapper"> <div class="container_24">

        <div class="footer">        <ul> <li><a href="http://encryptstick.com/">Home</a></li> <li><a href="http://encryptstick.com/what-is-encrypt-stick">About</a></li> <li><a href="http://encryptstick.com/download">Download Now!</a></li> <li><a href="http://encryptstick.com/products/encrypt-stick-instant-license.html"><strong>Buy Now!</strong></a></li> <li><a href="http://encryptstick.com/support">Support</a></li> <li><a href="http://encryptstick.com/press-room">Press Room</a></li> <li class="last"><a href="http://encryptstick.com/contact-us">Contact Us</a></li> </ul>           
            <ul class="links">
             <li class="start-small"><a href="/privacy-policy" class="small">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                <li class="last"><a href="/terms-conditions" class="small">Software License Agreement</a></li>
            </ul>

            <address>&copy; 2010 ENC Security Systems Inc. All Rights Reserved.</address>    </div>



<div class="social-media">    <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_32x32_style addthis_default_style">
    <a class="addthis_button_facebook"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_twitter"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_email"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_google"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>  </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#username=encsecurity"></script>


    <div class="verisign"><script class="alignright" type="text/javascript" src="https://seal.verisign.com/getseal?host_name=encryptstick.com&amp;size=S&amp;use_flash=YES&amp;use_transparent=YES&amp;lang=en"></script></div> </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>         
        </div> </div>
         <script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];  
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-17243877-1']);  
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async
= true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);   })();

</script></body> </html>
```

Comment: You'll have better luck on a webmaster oriented forum.  Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Comment: Maybe a webmaster forum like http://webmasters.stackexchange.com :D

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot seem to receive a google page rank" or "the site will not rank"? Any site indexed by Google has a PageRank, and that site is obviously indexed in Google. Therefore it has a PR and it's been ranked.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to be patient and get your site out there. Searching for `site:encryptstick.com` shows plenty of pages so the site is being indexed fine. A search for "encrypt stick" shows you as #1.

If you want to check Google Webmaster Tools for errors, the best place to look is Diagnostics > Crawl Errors. You might also like to try Yahoo's [Site Explorer](http://siteexplorer.search.yahoo.com/uk/siteexplorer/search?p=encryptstick.com).

If you want to rank for competitive keywords, it will simply take a while longer to build up links and generate buzz around your site.

Answer (score 1):

A Google search for [site:encryptstick.com](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aencryptstick.com) reports that your site is indexed and a search for ["encryption software for usb sticks"](http://www.google.com/search?q=encryption+software+for+usb+sticks) reveals that you are ranked ~71 on that term.

Most of your efforts (if you want to surpass your competition) should be directed toward building links - [however many](http://www.opensiteexplorer.org/encryptstick.com%252F/a!metrics) you've amassed, you'll likely need more (by orders of magnitude) to catch up to [truecrypt.com](http://www.opensiteexplorer.org/www.truecrypt.org%252F/a!metrics)

Answer (score 1):

don't forget that pagerank reported by the toolbar and other sites is not the PR that google use internally and is only updated twice a year or so.

Answer (score -1):

Jordan, when i Googled your site, i saw an ad from Google at the top suggesting you sign up for Google Webmaster Tools.

[image]

You should really do this, as it gives you all kinds of information about errors Google could be finding, and suggestions for improvement. The fact that they are serving this ad to you suggests to me that you haven't done this already.

Comment: Not always the case - I have a couple domains that have been near-idle but tracking in WT for the last year, and they still both get that on a site search.

Comment: Almost every `site:` query you run shows an ad for Google Webmaster Tools.

Comment: OK, thanks for clearing that up, i made an (incorrect) assumption that the ad was tied to Google knowing you hadn't already signed up.